# Actionscript MouseScroll / MouseDrag

Tags: events, scroll, actionscript, click, drag

Is there a "MouseScroll" or "MouseDrag" Event in Actionscript, I could not find something properly.
I have this:

```
resultPumpVolCalcBoxQv.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getPumpVolumenQv);
resultPumpVolCalcBoxQn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getPumpVolumenn);
resultPumpVolCalcBoxQvng.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getPumpVolumenng);

function getPumpVolumenQv(e:MouseEvent):void {

     pumpeVolQv = Number(pumpeVolumenstromTextFieldqv.text);
     pumpeVolN  = Number(pumpeVolumenstromTextFieldn.text);
     pumpeVolNg = Number(pumpeVolumenstromTextFieldng.text);
     if(pumpeVolumenstromTextFieldng.text != null && pumpeVolumenstromTextFieldn.text != null) {        
        totalqv = (pumpeVolNg * pumpeVolN)/1000
        pumpeVolumenstromTextFieldqv.text = " " + totalqv;
     } else {
         //
     }   
}
```

Currently this works with a click event.
I want to make this calculation happen if I drag something like a scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

You have to combine the usage of MouseDown and MouseOut to create a drag outcome

```
obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);

function mouseDown($e:MouseEvent):void{
MovieClip($e.currentTarget).startDrag();
}

function mouseUp($e:MouseEvent):void{
MovieClip($.currentTarget).stopDrag();
}
```

If you want it to constrain to an X or Y position, add a rectangular box paraments in the startDrag() functions

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the Mouse up and Mouse down events to achieve this. However, be careful to add and then remove the event listeners when they are not needed. This way you will ensure that the event listeners are properly removed and not added multiple times causing memory issues.

```
private var yourObject:MovieClip;

private function addDragListeners():void
{
    yourObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown, false, 0, true);
    yourObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseUp, false, 0, true);
}

private function removeDragListeners():void
{
    yourObject.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
    yourObject.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseUp);
}

protected function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    yourObject.startDrag();
}

protected function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    yourObject.stopDrag();
}
```

You can look into the startDrag() method in case you need to add some bounds for the dragging.